# Can My Wife apply to UK visa on my bank statment

Tags: visas, uk

My wife's brother who lives in UK has residency, but not nationality. He wants to sponsor his sister (My wife) for visit from Pakistan.

Now the question is that my **wife doesn't have any job**. She is just a house wife. Can she **use my bank statement for her visa application**?